# Stored procedure does not run

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I keep getting

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
```

when calling the stored procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spInflateRating;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE spInflateRating()

BEGIN

UPDATE mathdb.student SET student_rating = 1000 WHERE student_rating < 1000 LIMIT 99999;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

from eclipse with

```
CallableStatement myStat4 = myConn.prepareCall("{spInflateRating()}");
myStat4.execute();
```

When I run the procedure

```
UPDATE mathdb.student SET student_rating = 1000 WHERE student_rating < 1000 LIMIT 99999;
```

directly in MySQL workbench, however, it works smoothly.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using wrong syntax, compare it with the documentation: [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html)

> {?= call <procedure-name>[(<arg1>,<arg2>, ...)]} 
>    {call
>   <procedure-name>[(<arg1>,<arg2>, ...)]}

Use `{call spInflateRating}` but not `{spInflateRating()}`